# Improve accuracy of counting blobs using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect blobs using opencv, however my accuracy haven't been any more that 80%.
Here are images of detected blobs:

Found blobs n = 350

[image]

Found blobs n = 550

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification


plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
n_samples = 250
x, _ = make_classification(n_samples = n_samples)
plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], marker='o', s=14 )
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('sampleblobs.jpg')
plt.show()

img = cv2.imread('sampleblobs.jpg',0)

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

params.filterByArea = False
params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 1
params.thresholdStep = 10;
params.minRepeatability = 2;
params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 0;

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

keypoints = detector.detect(img)
print('Found: {}, Original: {}'.format(len(keypoints), n_samples))

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,100), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow("Found blobs", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.imwrite("Found_blobs.jpg", im_with_keypoints)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Is there any way to improve an accuracy in this case?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might have to opt for a different approach because many blobs are overlapping. Have you tried watershed algorithm?

Comment: Watershed is a good idea. You might also try doing some morphology on your image before blob detection to shrink the dots so that they're separated. cv.morphologyEx(inputImage, cv.MORPH_DILATE...